# how to play video with native player instead of web player for a <video> tag?

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview

We have a UIWebView that load html page including video tag. When the user tap the video element, a fullscreen movie player is presented.
As there is some logic in the web page that handle events and need to stop and close the movie player.   Is there any API to do so (stop the web movie player and exit fullscreen)?

Any one know how to do this?

Further more, even we want to detect tapping on the video element, then we'll have to provide our own custom player, instead of the system web player. Any way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might be helping, if you want to controll the HTML5 video with js: http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

I am not shure if - on a mobile device - javascript will be running while the video is in fullscreen mode.